# Crop fields dataset

Tags: machine-learning, images, agriculture

Somebody knows where to find some images from crop fields for machine learning classification problems?. Like coffee or grape fields.

I need some aerial images, can be from drones or satelital, but I'm struggling to find ones from unhealthy fields (like drought, pests, etc).

If somebody knows about datasets for this I will appreciate it so much.

Answer (score 1):

[CropScape - Cropland Data Layer](https://nassgeodata.gmu.edu/CropScape/) by USDA has this data. More information: [CropScape and Cropland Data Layer - Research and Science - USDA](https://www.nass.usda.gov/Research_and_Science/Cropland/SARS1a.php)