# Where can I find image dataset for crop yield prediction?

Tags: data-request, images, agriculture

I want to reproduce the work from the research paper [Crop Biometric Maps: The Key to Prediction](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3821323/) by
Francisco Rovira-Más and Verónica Sáiz-Rubio, but I need the right dataset for that. Where can I find it?

Comment: [related?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/11873/1511). In general, for questions about a specific paper, it's best to contact the authors (and post links to any data as an answer to this question)

Answer (score 1):

[GAEZ](http://gaez.fao.org) by FAO has agro-climatic suitability, potential / actual yield, and other data products for a variety of crops under different conditions.  Model documentation can be found [here](http://www.fao.org/fileadmin/user_upload/gaez/docs/GAEZ_Model_Documentation.pdf).