# How can I access GAEZ potential yield rasters?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, agriculture

I need rasters of global potential yields for various crops globally for a research project. These rasters are available from [GAEZ](http://www.fao.org/nr/gaez/en/), as pointed out in the answer to [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/15281/where-can-i-find-image-dataset-for-crop-yield-prediction).

However, the GAEZ data portal, an Adobe Flash web app, does not work for me. I am not able to download the data rasters (though I am able to download data in an aggregated tabular format). I've tried clearing my cache, switching browsers, etc. I've also had colleagues try to download the data without success. I've emailed GAEZ repeatedly about this over the last few months and have not received any reply.

Does anyone either have this data downloaded and would be willing to share it, or have troubleshooting tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a separate data portal maintained by the IIASA which has this data: http://www.gaez.iiasa.ac.at/

Comment: is that a URI? it does not resolve for me...

Comment: I added the www subdomain and it seems to work